# How to reduce the gap/spacing between two bullet-point lines in Overleaf LaTeX?

Tags: latex, overleaf

In this image I have shown the bullet points in Overleaf LaTeX when I was creating my resume. How do I reduce the gap between these bullet point lines? My current code looks like this:

```
\csection{COURSEWORK}{\small
    \begin{itemize}
        % item 1 %
        \item \frcontent{Data Structures and Algorithms}{}{}{}
        % item 2 %
        \item \frcontent{Design and Analysis of Algorithms}{}{}{}
        % item 3 %
        \item \frcontent{Database Management Systems}{}{}{}
        % item 3 %
        \item \frcontent{Object Oriented Programming}{}{}{}
    \end{itemize}
}
```

Output image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKkHT.jpg

Comment: please make a compilable [mre] that shows us from which class/package such non-standard macros like `\csection` come from

Answer (score 0):

**`\frcontent`** is not required here.
You can do the following:

```
\csection{COURSEWORK}{\small
    \begin{itemize}
        % item 1 %
        \item Data Structures and Algorithms
        % item 2 %
        \item Design and Analysis of Algorithms
        % item 3 %
        \item Database Management Systems
        % item 3 %
        \item Object Oriented Programming
    \end{itemize}
}
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qdRw.png)

NB: You can use **\textbf** to bold. For example:

```
\item \textbf{Data Structures and Algorithms}
```